# R Cubist processing time 3x longer than Random Forests

Tags: r, random-forest

I am working with raster datasets and employing different rule-based algorithms (namely, CART, Cubist, bagged trees, boosted trees and random forests "RF") for a regression problem (biomass per area).

My initial reasoning was that Cubist would have an optimal prediction performance and require low processing power/time for predictions. The reasons for such should be the low complexity fit between predictors and explained variable.

Result wise, Cubist has performed as well as RF  (as per the results of Dunn's Test, using the results of a k-fold repeated cross-validation). M5, on the other hand, is lightning-fast (3 seconds), but  not as accurate as RF.

However, and quite surprisingly, Cubist took around one minute, whereas Random Forest needed 19 seconds, to predict the same raster. The same results were reported in this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neunet.2018.12.010

I would be happy to provide a reprex, if provided a mock-up raster (in which I could perform regression and not classification, although computing time should not be determined by the task).  I've seen one of your talks, where you mentioned that Cubist should be faster than Random Forests (provided that is coded in C and is far smaller and optimized, rather than Random Forest).

The size of a Cubist model is around 100kb whereas RF, 5Mb. However, this (in the context where I am working) is not a limiting factor.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I would argue that Cubist should be the work-horse (for tasks such as mine) rather than Random Forest; however, as is, Cubist will be limited by the processing-time

Cheers, Gustavo

Comment: Options: Cubist is doing higher-order linear regression while RF does windowed means?  Cubist might be compiled for single core not multiple cores.

Comment: @EngrStudent: I've considered the possibility of Cubist not been able to deal with parallel optimization. As I am using caret, I have run the same analysis with the option `(trainControl(allowParalallel= T/F)` both using True and False.

I understand that for prediction Cubist may not be implemented to be performed in multiple cores, however I have failed to find that sort of information.

Comment: If you are a windows box with multiple cores then open task manager and look at the "performance" tab for CPU.  It usually shows me the cores I have all split out.  If something is doing a good job of utilization then the aggregate is more than 80%.  If only one core is running, I can see it clearly in the plot.

Comment: You can ask a moderator to have this moved to StackOverflow and those folks might help much more effectively than here in CV.  They tend to be "symbol manipulation" dominant, code is tertiary.  ;)